# Exiting While Loop from Recursive Function

Tags: vba, excel

I've written this code to delete duplicate rows in a column of an Excel spreadsheet. I'm not sure how to, or if it is possible to, exit the while loop from within the function itself. I don't want to add a second condition to the loop (such as `Counter < 100`) because I don't want it to run more than needed.

```
Sub Deletion()
Dim Cond As Boolean
Dim Counter As Integer
Cond = True
Counter = 2
    While Cond = True
    RecDel (Counter)
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Function RecDel(Varii As Integer)
Set CurrentCell = Workbooks("Duplicate.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Varii, 2)
        If CurrentCell.Value = CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value And CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" Then
                Workbooks("Duplicate.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Varii + 1).Delete
                RecDel (Varii) 'Repeats deletion until this row and the next row are different
        ElseIf CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
            Cond = False  'This can't change the global variable and break the loop
        Else
        End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Cond` in the function and the `Cond` in the sub are not the same. They are both local variables. You could make `Cond` global to share it between the 2. Alternatively, you could have your function return a Boolean and get rid of the `Cond` flag altogether:

```
Function RecDel(Varii As Integer) As Boolean
    Set CurrentCell = Workbooks("Duplicate.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Varii, 2)
    If CurrentCell.Value = CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value And CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" Then
        Workbooks("Duplicate.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Varii + 1).Delete
        RecDel = RecDel (Varii) 'Repeats deletion until this row and the next row are different
    ElseIf CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
        RecDel = False  'This can't change the global variable and break the loop
    End If
End Function
```

And in your calling sub, check the status of RecDel:

```
While RecDel (Counter) = True
    Counter = Counter + 1
Wend
```